Determine column to insert into based on content
Imagine I have rows of data in a postgres table, such as:



Id
Value




1
User_1


2
Region_3


3
User_2



And I want to select out values in a way that uses the part of Value before the _ character to determine which column to populate, such that the results would be:



Id
User
Region




1
1
null


2
null
3


3
2
null



There would only need to be a fixed number of values that would only ever be small. Is there a way to do this in SQL?
I can see that it's possible to populate cells with different values such as in this answer, but I have not been able to find any details on populating a column based on the content of a row.
I've been able to get the relevant part of the value out using left:
SELECT
left("Value", strpos("Value", '_') - 1) as "Type"

But I cannot see how I would take this and use it determining the column.

use the case statement.
here is the fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nTapovF5r5b8U4Tmjhy4tU/1
select id, 
case  split_part(value, '_', 1)
    when 'User' then split_part(value, '_', 2)
    end as User,
 case  split_part(value, '_', 1)
    when 'Region' then split_part(value, '_', 2)
    end as Region
from tableone;


Fantastic! Thank you, I was not aware you could use case like that

@OliverRadini Please note this answer is good and will work as long as you only need those hard coded two options, Region or User. If you need a dynamic solution which produces exactly those columns that occur in your data, this would be more complex. I think you should at least edit your question to point out you don't need a dynamic query if you really don't.

Case expression.

For more columns, split the string once in a subquery, and add a cast once (if all share the same target type), and use a CASE expression per column in the outer SELECT:
SELECT id
     , CASE WHEN key = 'User'   THEN value END AS "User"
     , CASE WHEN key = 'Region' THEN value END AS "Region"
FROM  (
   SELECT id
        , split_part(value, '_', 1) AS key
        , split_part(value, '_', 2)::int AS value  -- cast?
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub;

fiddle
Related:

Split comma separated column data into additional columns

For more than a few target columns, or to combine multiple values with the same id value in a single row (not the case in your sample values!), consider a crosstab() query:
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
   $$
   SELECT id
        , split_part(value, '_', 1) AS key
        , split_part(value, '_', 2) AS value
   FROM   tbl
-- ORDER  BY id  -- not needed for single value per target row (?)
   $$

 , $$VALUES ('User'::text), ('Region')$$        -- more?
   ) AS ct (id int, "User" int, "Region" int);  -- more?

fiddle
This also casts value columns from text to int implicitly.
See:

PostgreSQL Crosstab Query


A little bit messy but I hope self explanatory.
select
  tbl.id,
  nullif(max(c) filter(where c != 'User'), 'Region') as "user",
  nullif(max(c) filter(where c != 'Region'), 'User') as region
from
  tbl,
  string_to_table(tbl.val, '_') as c
group by tbl.id
;

db<>fiddle
